# Is it really against the Torah to speak Loshon Hora about yourself?

Tags: halacha, speech-talking, bein-adam-lachavero, chofetz-chaim, loshon-hara

Is it true that it is an aveirah to speak badly about yourself to someone else?

Comment: You definitely shouldn't be _motzi shem ra_ about yourself

Comment: I saw some of your other answers which were deleted. Since MY is different from other sites you might be used to, see [here](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) for a guide which might help understand the site. Amonst others Mi Yodeya isn't like a standard internet discussion forum -- we're strictly a Q&A site, where we expect answers to answer the question at hand and source them. Great to have you learn with us!

Comment: It’s prob not a good thing